# Direct image of the ideal sheaf of the diagonal embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme and $I$ be the ideal sheaf of the diagonal embedding $\Delta:X\hookrightarrow X\times X$. Denote by $p: X\times X\to X$ the projection on the first component. Is it true that $p_*I = 0$? This question boils down to the question what is the pushforward of the quotient map $\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}\to\Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X$ along $p$. It is either $0$ or identity but I am not sure what the correct answer is.

Comment: Try some examples: can you do $\Bbb A^1$ and $\Bbb P^1$?

Comment: If my computations in local coordinates are correct then in the case $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ the ideal sheaf $I$ is isomorphic to $p^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1))\otimes q^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1))$, where $q: X\times X\to X$ is the projection on the second component. Then $p_*I = 0$ by the projection formula and flat base change.

Comment: Yep, I agree with the sheaf and the result - you can also see that by considering the long exact sequence in cohomology associated to $0\to I \to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1}\to\Delta_*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}\to0$. What happens for $\Bbb A^1$? This was a two-part hint, after all.

Comment: In affine case we always have $H^1(X\times X, I) = 0$ so the long exact sequence of cohomologies says that the only possibility is $p_*I=0$.

Comment: No, that's not true. Do the computation for $\Bbb A^1$! The ideal sheaf is the quasi-coherent sheaf associated to $(x_1-x_2)$, so...

Comment: Okay, I see. If $X$ if affine then $p_*\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}$ is not a coherent module over $X$ and thus $p_*I\neq 0$. But is it true that if $X$ is projective then $p_*I=0$? I expect that the functor $p_*$ should send the restriction map $\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}\to\Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X$ to the identity map $p_*\mathcal{O}_{X\times X}\cong\mathcal{O}_X\to p_*\Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X\cong\mathcal{O}_X$.